# How can I reproduce this "minimalist" background?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background, illustrator-effects

I am making a game and I wanted to make a background for it. It is a board game so I was thinking of keeping it minimal. Surfing the web, I found this picture and got really intrigued by the simplicity and relaxing feeling I get from it. I am a novice at Illustrator and I am wondering on how I can make the background effect that is displayed in the picture.

[image]

Comment: It is very important when writing articles, questions etc. To repeat the message in the title and section in the body text itself. This is due to a quirk in human memory called the doorway effect. In essence each of these things are a different state and they all need to be separately 'tagged'

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Edit:** I accidentally posted this for Photoshop and failed to notice the Illustrator tag. However, I'll leave this answer here should anyone find it useful.

Here's one possible method.

1. Fill the canvas with a light blue such as #98bcd4
2. Do *Image > Mode > 16bits/channel*.  This will help reduce banding in the final step.
3. Choose a large soft edged brush about half the size of the canvas, and lower the opacity to something like 10% in the tool options along the top.
4. Paint in the middle of the canvas, doing small circular motions with the brush, several times, until you get a nice gradient.

Example

[image]

Comment: In illustrator?

Comment: @BillyKerr pretty sure this is for Photoshop. Anyways, I did it in photoshop and looks good

Comment: @DMH16 yeah, oops it's for photoshop. Didn't see your tag. Illustrator isn't so good for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 10):

The background there is simply a radial gradient white to blue

[image]

If you want a bit more control and a smoother "fade", which is not necessarily elliptical, you can use a **Gradient Mesh**. Set the outer points to a color and the center point to white. Then adjust the mesh handles/points.

[image]

Comment: I'm using an older version of Illustrator. The standard radial/linear gradients seem to not diffuse the edges as well for the *screen preview*. It's merely an inherent limitation in the standard gradients (code is probably 30 years old for those). The edges are *much less* apparent on output. But that doesn't always help for display-destined art. Also, these are screen shots, not exports, so that may factor a bit. This is often why I may default to a simple mesh as opposed to a standard gradient.